Why does my dogs skin, change color?
My dogs skin is pink in the winter then turns brown in the summer

many pets have fur that get bleached by the sun and skin that gets darker when exposed to the suns uv-a and uv-b radiation,people too have hair that gets bleached by the sun and skin that gets a tan.
